# Type variable string as text VBS

Tags: vbscript

I'm new to VBS, just trying to figure out how I can run a script which prompts the user for input, & then types that result as part of a sentence?

I'm using WshShell.SendKeys as I want the script to be flexible & able to enter the text into different programs, would there be a way to have this type something that was entered into an InputBox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple example of how to get InputBox to take your input, then send the keys to a command prompt. I think you can work out how to adapt this for any other program pretty easily.

```
Option Explicit

Dim a
a = InputBox("Enter your name", "Example")

Dim sh
Set sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "cmd"
WScript.Sleep 200 
sh.AppActivate "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" 
WScript.Sleep 200 
sh.SendKeys "echo Hello " & a & "!"
sh.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

When you run this and enter the word "CrowStorm", CMD will open and echo the sentence "Hello CrowStorm!"

Answer (score 0):

This would work if you were trying to put this into notepad:

```
Option Explicit
    Dim WshShell,input
    Set WshShell =CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    input = InputBox("Enter your name", "Example")
    WshShell.Run("notepad")
    WScript.Sleep 200 
    Wshshell.SendKeys "Hello " & input & "!"
    WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```